# Truncating text into ellipsis in a fluid div inside table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column fix left and right layout, with middle layout as fluid as below. It works perfectly as currently. However, if i add a truncate class to it, the middle div width will expand over the parent width.

So, my question is: How to truncate text in fluid layout and fix the truncated text inside the fluid layout width. Do note that I do not expect to hard code the middle div width.

Plunkr before adding truncate class: [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/L5DSJ14Ff5eewnRUJkHH?p=preview)

If replace `div class=middle` into this, it will fail to truncate text.

```
<div class="middle">
        <div class="truncate">This is a very long text that should be truncate</div>
        <div class="truncate">This is a verry very long text that should be truncated</div>
      </div>
```

Sample expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code to achieve the same.

```
<div class="three-column-wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="truncate">This is a very long text that should be truncate This is a verry very long text that should be truncated</div>
    <div class="truncate">This is a verry very long text that should be truncated</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    123
  </div>
</div>

    .three-column-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.left {
    width: 40px;
}

.left, .middle, .right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.middle {
    background: red;
}
.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have added table-layout:fixed to the parent to ensure that the child div share equal width if no width mentioned. And also it doesn't wrap if width is mentioned. Then i have added width to the truncate class. Note that ellipsis will not work without width mentioned. Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sjbjm9n0/)

Answer (score 1):

use this below css and it may help you...

```
.middle div {
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 font-size :35px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here, have fun.

```css
.table{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}


.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
}

.table td > .text-tuncate, .table th > .text-tuncate{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td><span class="text-tuncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis feugiat mi, id bibendum tellus. </span></td>
      <td><span class="text-tuncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis feugiat mi, id bibendum tellus. </span></td>
      <td><span class="text-tuncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis feugiat mi, id bibendum tellus. </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```